# Your app is having trouble loading the streamlit_chat.streamlit_chat component

Tags: streamlit, langchain

I'm facing issues when running a stremlit app locally.
I get the following error: Your app is having trouble loading the streamlit_chat.streamlit_chat component

This error comes up when I try to run the stramlit up. The app will open but the error message shows immediately and I'm not able to access the steamlit chat component.

This is the code I have:

```html
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_chat import message
import tempfile
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader, DirectoryLoader
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.llms import CTransformers
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain

DB_FAISS_PATH = "vectorstore/db_faiss"

# loading the model
def load_llm():
    llm = CTransformers(
        model = "llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin",
        model_type= "llama",
        max_new_tokens= 512,
        temperature= 0.7
    )
    return llm

st.title("Chat with your Documents using GenAI ")
st.markdown("<h3 style='text-align: center; color: black;'>Built</h3>", unsafe_allow_html=True)


uploaded_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Upload your PDF file", type="pdf")

if uploaded_file:
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp_file:
        tmp_file.write(uploaded_file.getvalue())
        tmp_file_path = tmp_file.name

    loader = PyPDFLoader(file_path=tmp_file_path)
    data = loader.load()
    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2",
                                       model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})
    db = FAISS.from_documents(data, embeddings)
    db.save_local(DB_FAISS_PATH)
    llm = load_llm()
    chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm=llm, retriever=db.as_retriever())

    def conversational_chat(query):
        result = chain({"question": query, "chat_history": st.session_state['history']})
        st.session_state['history'].append((query, result["answer"]))
        return result["answer"]
    
    if 'history' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['history'] = []

    if 'generated' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['generated'] = ["Hello ! Ask me anything about " + uploaded_file.name + " "]

    if 'past' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['past'] = ["Hey ! "]
        
    #container for the chat history
    response_container = st.container()
    #container for the user's text input
    container = st.container()

    with container:
        with st.form(key='my_form', clear_on_submit=True):
            
            user_input = st.text_input("Query:", placeholder="Talk to your pdf data here (:", key='input')
            submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Send')
            
        if submit_button and user_input:
            output = conversational_chat(user_input)
            
            st.session_state['past'].append(user_input)
            st.session_state['generated'].append(output)

    if st.session_state['generated']:
        with response_container:
            for i in range(len(st.session_state['generated'])):
                message(st.session_state["past"][i], is_user=True, key=str(i) + '_user', avatar_style="big-smile")
                message(st.session_state["generated"][i], key=str(i), avatar_style="thumbs")
```

Can anyone help me understand what's the issue here?
Thank you!

Comment: what is the error ?, not able to run your code snippet

Comment: the error is that, when i launch the app it says: Your app is having trouble loading the streamlit_chat.streamlit_chat component. So basically there are issue in loading the streamlit_chat component

Answer (score 1):

Found the error. Streamlit-chat needed to be set to 0.0.2.2.

Comment: I think that adding some detail about how to apply the change that would fix the issue raised by user would add a lot of value to your answer.

Comment: This worked. Just change the version of streamlit-chat to "==0.0.2.2" in the Pipfile file and then run command pipenv install. This will update the Pipfile.lock and install the desired version. Assuming you're using pipenv. If not, run command pip install streamlit-chat==0.0.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below steps.

```
 pip install streamlit
 pip install streamlit_chat
 pip install ctransformers
```

you can run test program to load the model locally

```
from ctransformers import AutoModelForCausalLM
load_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML", model_file="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin")
```

Now load this model from local directory

```
       def load_llm():
        llm = CTransformers(
            model =r"C:\Users\your_id\.cache\huggingface\hub\models--TheBloke--Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML\llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin",
            model_type= "llama",
            max_new_tokens= 512,
            temperature= 0.7
        )
        return llm
```

[image]